# Change textbox to textarea on click

Tags: javascript, user-interface, extjs, textarea

How do I convert a simple text box to text area when the user clicks on it. I'm using EXT JS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you doing it just for visual appearance? Or is there a valid reason for converting it from input to textarea?

If you are doing it just for the visuals of it you can get a long way with just setting the height of your textarea and in the focus event increase the height.

```
Ext.onReady(function(){

    new Ext.form.TextArea({
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        name: 'myTextArea',
        width: 200,
        height: 22,
        listeners: {
            focus: function(textarea){
                textarea.setHeight(200);
            },
            blur: function(textarea){
                textarea.setHeight(22);
            }
        }
    });

});
```

EDIT: These stopped working:

<s>Try it here: http://jsfiddle.net/chrisramakers/9FjGv/2/</s>

You can even quite easily animate it for some extra fancy visualy fancy pancy.
http://jsfiddle.net/chrisramakers/9FjGv/3/

Comment: @TimCoker yes it seems the external extjs libraries and css files are no longer hosted where they used to be ...

Answer (score 2):

You can't change a textbox to a textarea because they are two different types of elements. You can however hide one and display the other.

```
<input type='text' id='myTextBox' />
<textarea id='myTextArea' />
```

With some function that could swap them on whatever event you want:

```
function swapTexts() {
    var tb = document.getElementById('myTextBox');
    var ta = document.getElementById('myTextArea');
    if (tb.style.display !== 'none') {
        tb.style.display = 'none';
        ta.style.display = '';
    } else {
        tb.style.display = '';
        ta.style.display = 'none';
    }        
}
```

Answer (score 2):

show and hide is nice technic. but., u can use innerHTML property also like this...

```
<div id='test'> <input type="text" name="text1" id="text1" onclick="test()"/></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function test()
{
    document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = "<textarea></textarea>"
}
</script>
```

if u want to change again, give some condition or any event.. this may help u i think..

have a good day.....

Comment: may i know this one fullfills your needs r not..?

Answer (score 1):

You can have two separate controls of `TextBox` and `TextArea` in the same div (or table) and then show the `TextArea` on click of `TextBox`

```
<input type='text' onclick='document.getElementById("txtArId").style.display = ""' />
<TextArea id='txtArId' />
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example done in jQuery.

HTML:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <input name="textInputComment" type="text" value="">
        <textarea name="textAreaComment" style="display: none;"></textarea>
    </td>
</tr>
```

jQuery:

```
 $(document).ready(function()

         $(document).on('focusin', 'input[name=textInputComment]', function () {
              $(this).hide();
              textarea = $(this).closest('tr').find('textarea[name=textAreaComment]');
              textarea.show().focus().val($(this).val());//show, focus and get value from input
         });

         $(document).on('focusout', 'textarea[name=textAreaComment]', function () {
              $(this).hide();
              textarea = $(this).closest('tr').find('input[name=textInputComment]');
              textarea.show().val($(this).val());//get value from textarea
         });
  });
```